# CSS class issue: "Today" and "All time" columns of Review are misaligned (on some sites)

Tags: bug, review, design

The "Today" and "All Time" columns of the Review history section (accessible through `site/review/close/stats` and similar for the other queues) are misaligned due to a CSS issue (it apparently doesn't show up on each site because some sites have no relevant settings on the CSS class in question):

[image: Exhibition of issue]

Looking at the source code, the `div` containing the left column is given by:

`<div class="task-stat-leaderboard user-info" style="float: left;"> ... </div>`

whereas the right column is given by:

`<div class="task-stat-leaderboard" style="float: left;"> ... </div>`

If I perform an in-line edit to add the `user-info` class to the right column, the top margin disappears. So it should be easy to fix (the other solution of course being the removal of the `user-info` class from the left column).

Comment: Doesn't happen here or on SO. You should have posted this on Math's meta. Also always add what browser you're using when posting things like this.

Comment: How could I have known? I only have access to the review pane on Mathematics.SE.

Comment: Each site has its own design and its own meta, questions/bugs about the design should go to the site's meta. If they happen to be global, they'll be migrated (or fixed right there).

Comment: Humm... happens on Programmers and U&L too.

Comment: While each site has its own design, it's not inconceivable that the HTML for the review page is universal. And the problem is with the classes between the two columns being wrong. Thus while it may not show on SO or MSO, it likely _is_ universal.

Comment: I'll take your point on board though; in the future I'll post design-related stuff on the local meta first.